# customize antd input placeholder color didn't work

Tags: reactjs, antd

I try to change placeholder of antd input but it didn't work
how should I find classes name in antd?

how can change placeholder color

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change placeholder color, you can change like that.

```
const StyledInput = styled(Input)`  
    &::placeholder{
      color:#fad
    }    
`;
-----------------------
same like - nromal css
input{
    &::placeholder{
      color:#fad
    }    
}
```

if you use theme token to apply all component as a global style, you can put like that

```
export const theme = {
  token: {
    colorPrimary: "#F06D24",
    colorLink: "#00AA67",
  },
  components: {
    Input: {
      controlHeight: 48,
      borderRadius: 4,
      colorTextPlaceholder: "#fad"
    }
  }
};
```